# retrieving values from a dynamic textbox whose is a combination of other values

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" value="${childOrders.code}" id="childOrderId-${orderHistory.code}-${childOrders.code}"/>
```

I need to retrieve the value of this dynamic text box which is inside a c:forEach loop.
i tried the wildcard selector way but was unsuccessful.

```
var orderCd=$(this).text();
var orderCdInt=parseInt(orderCd);

alert(orderCdInt);

$.each($("input[id^='childOrderId- +orderCdInt+-']"), function(i, item) { //uses wildcard selector
    alert("1");
    var grade =  $(item).val();  //Use item instead of selector
    alert(grade);
});
```

Comment: How specifically was it unsuccessful?  Did the selector simply not find the elements you expect it to?  What are those actual elements in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

var selector = 'childOrderId-'+orderCdInt+'-'
$.each($("input[id^=selector]"), function(i, item) {

Comment: var selector = 'childOrderId-'+orderCdInt+'-'